# Trying to build solution (debug it) and recieving an error saying the .exe is missing

Tags: c#, debugging, error-handling

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace as2
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int id = 0, stock = 0, published = 0, newstock = 0;
      double price = 0.00;
      string type = " ", title = " ", author = " ";

      Program inventroy = new Program();
      inventroy.read_one_record(id, stock, published, 
        price, type, title, author);

      Console.WriteLine("Update Number In Stock");
      Console.WriteLine("=======================");
      Console.Write("Item ID: ");
      Console.Write(id);
      Console.WriteLine("Item Type: ");
      Console.Write(type);
    }

    void read_one_record(int id, int stock, int published, 
      double price, string type, string title, string author)
    {
      StreamReader myFile = File.OpenText("Inventory.dat");

      id = myFile.Read();
      stock = myFile.Read();
      published = myFile.Read();
      stock = myFile.Read();
      price = myFile.Read();
      type = myFile.ReadLine();
      title = myFile.ReadLine();
      author = myFile.ReadLine();

      myFile.Close();
    }

    void write_one_record(int id, int newstock, 
      int published, double price, string type, 
      string title, string author)
    {
      StreamWriter myFile = File.OpenWrite("Inventory.dat");

      myFile.WriteLine(id);
      myFile.WriteLine(newstock);
      myFile.WriteLine(published);
      myFile.WriteLine(price);
      myFile.WriteLine(type);
      myFile.WriteLine(title);
      myFile.WriteLine(author);

      myFile.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Code is meant to open an inventory file, pull in the info, pass it back to main where in main I will ask the user to update the stock #. Then pass that number to `writefunction` where it writes it. For some reason when I try to launch to see if it works (code is not 100$ complete yet should still compile). It says something along the lines that the projects .exe is missing and cannot debug.

Comment: Do a manual build (F6). Is the exe now present? What does the output windows say? Does it say success?

Comment: It did not, however when I changed the streamwriter as Joachim Isaksson suggested it did launch. However, there were errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting an EXE because you have an error in your code at the line

```
StreamWriter myFile = File.OpenWrite("Inventory.dat");
```

A FileStream isn't the same as a StreamWriter, but you can create a StreamWriter using

```
StreamWriter myFile = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("Inventory.dat"));
```

Comment: Does it matter which I use? Or rather, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: @nogg StreamWriters (all Writers really) are good at handling text, while FileStreams (as all Streams) are good at handling raw data. In this case you want text, so StreamWriter is a good choice.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Also your advice worked quite excellently.

Comment: If you could look at my code a little bit further, for some reason It isn't outputting the ID (Im just doing ID and Type to test and make sure it works) and type. Im not sure if it is a issue when first taking the info, or if it is getting lost in transferring from the void function to the main.

Comment: @Nogg Well, there are two things, the parameters you pass to the function are passed by value (that is, whatever you change them to in the function won't affect the value in main), you should read up on the "out" and "ref" keywords in C#. Also you're using Read() to read the data, but Read only returns one character. You probably want ReadLine instead.

Comment: I will read up on ref. But when I change read to readLine, I get an error. id = myFile.ReadLine(); saying it cannot change string to int.

Comment: @Nogg ReadLine returns a string, if you want to assign it to an int, you need to convert it http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-parse